# Yii2 Oracle procedure with cursor

Tags: php, oracle, stored-procedures, pdo, yii

I have a **Oracle** stored procedure that has an IN OUT cursor parameter.

```
SP_GET_RATES
(     
 M_CHECKIN_DATE VARCHAR2,
 M_CHECKOUT_DATE  VARCHAR2,
 M_CURRENCY VARCHAR2,
 M_RESULT   IN OUT  SASIAPLSQLTAB.SEARCH_RESULT_CURSOR
)
```

In Yii2 im trying to use this method to get the procedure result.

```
$params = array(            
        ':1' => '20-Nov-2015',
        ':2' => '21-Nov-2015',
        ':3' => 'USD'                 
    );

    $stmt = $connection->createCommand("CALL SP_GET_RATES(:1,:2,:3,:4)", $params);
    $stmt->bindParam(':4', $return_cursor,\PDO::PARAM_STR|\PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT,4000);
    $stmt->queryAll();
```

But when executing this I'm getting error.

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 6553 OCIStmtExecute: ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SP_GET_RATES'
(ext\pdo_oci\oci_statement.c:148)
The SQL being executed was: CALL SP_GET_RATES('20-Nov-2015','21-Nov-2015','USD',NULL)
```

I tried differnt ways to bind the values but still I can't figure out how to bind IN OUT cursor parameter in Yii2. And I think Yii2 using PDO OCI to connect oracle database.

Yii 2.0.6
PHP 5.5.24
Oracle 11g

Answer (score 1):

Seem you are calling a SP with four argument

```
 CALL SP_GET_RATES(:1,:2,:3,:4)
```

but you pass only three or you use the wrong type for the value

```
 $params = array(            
    ':1' => '20-Nov-2015',
    ':2' => '21-Nov-2015',
    ':3' => 'USD'                 
);
```

Comment: No. im adding the 4th parameter as bindParam

$stmt->bindParam(':4', $return_cursor,\PDO::PARAM_STR|\PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT,4000);

Answer (score 0):

PDO::oci does not support REF CURSORS. Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-oci.php

But for Yii there is a workaround by using oci8 which supports cursors and is well supported by Yii.

Yii has oci8 extensions. Which makes using oci8 easier and its better in terms of perfomrnce compared to pdo_oci. Reference: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/oci8pdo